# How to combine tables in qlikview

Tags: join, merge, where-clause, qlikview

How can I merge two or three tables into one single table and make a big master table in QlikView?

**Scenario** : I have following 3 Tables. They all contain different facts but i want to merge them and make a big fact table.

### (Table#1) Order_Case

### OrderID  |  CaseID  |  CustomerID  |  WorkFlowID

### (Table#2) Work_Flow

### WorkFlowID  |  WorkFlowStatus  |  CreatedDate  |

### (Table#3) Product_Detail

### CaseID  |  ProductID  |  SupplierID  |

**What I am trying to achieve :** is I want to merge all this tables into a single table so the matching field data should merge and if the field does not match then it should show NULL against it.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hi i have tried inner, outer, right and left joins

Comment: Concatenate? https://community.qlik.com/thread/39177

Comment: Yeah tried that too.. but concatenate and doesnt merge the way i want.. I am looking for something like WHERE IN Clause in SQL but it doesnt work in QlikView!

Comment: Aha. Can you please add example of the raw data and what is expected as result?

Comment: For what it's worth, in Qlikview, because of the way it associates field names, the behavior you want within a Qlikview app should be available to you right out of the box. You wouldn't need to join these table since Qlik would essentially do that for you and behave as if they were joined. If you did want to manually join the tables though, using left joins in the script should take care of it. This is a pretty basic use case. Try looking [here](https://community.qlik.com/thread/39177).

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine, if its not, than you have a problem in one of the "key/join" fields:

`Load OrderID ,CaseID,CustomerID,WorkFlowID resident Table#1;
join // or left join
Load WorkFlowID,WorkFlowStatus,CreatedDate resident Table#2;
join
load CaseID,ProductID,SupplierID resident Table#3;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those merging... as long you have the same Field Name
(as I noticed)

Order_case will be connected to Work_flow by field WorkflowID

and

Order_case will also be connected to Product_Detail by field CaseID

You just need to LOAD them in sequence (all three)

These are star-scheme fact tables, it is quite common and applicable in qlikview, you'll just need to "play along" with the filtering

Hope this can help...